# How to get each paragraph as a separate answer unit in Watson Conversion Service?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I have a pdf document where I have a heading with bold and size 12 and there are paragraphs under the heading of size 10.

I have custom configuration for Level 1 and Level 2 for size 12 Bold and 10 respectively.

But when I call the api I get all the paragraphs in one answer unit only. Is there any way by which I can get each paragraph as a separate answer unit ?

```
String configAsString = "{" + "\"pdf\":{" + "\"heading\":{" + "\"fonts\":[" + "{\"level\":1,\"min_size\":12,\"bold\": true,\"name\":\"Calibri\"},"
                        + "{\"level\":2,\"max_size\":10}" + "]}}}";
```

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about Watson Conversation? Or Watson Discovery?

Comment: Watson Conversion I am talking about

Comment: Watson conversation doesn't store PDFs. Nor does it have "custom configurations". Sounds more like Discovery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly your use case, but in general you can send multiple answers instead of one by chaining several dialog nodes with "Jump to (and respond)".